# Column width for Angular2 Generic Table

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using Angular2 and `generic-table` as below:

```
<generic-table
  #notesTable
  [gtClasses]="'table-sm table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'"
  [gtSettings]="configObject.settings"
  [gtFields]="configObject.fields"
  [(gtData)]="configObject.data"
  [gtOptions]="{csvDelimiter: ',', reportColumnWidth: true, numberOfRows: 30}">
</generic-table>

<td class="timestamp-column timestamp" ng-reflect-ng-class="timestamp-column    timestamp">

.timestamp, .timestamp-column {
    width: 45px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

How does one specify the `column-width` for each column?

Inspecting elements of the page each column has its own class `name-column`, etc., but when setting CSS attributes for this `.name-column {}`  does nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest you to read the docs of generic-table: https://hjalmers.github.io/angular-generic-table/styling ... Use gtClasses input to append class names to the table element or use it as property of the fields array passed to gtFields like in the example: columnClass: (row, col) => { ...

Answer (score -1):

You can still use **th:nth-child(n)**  n will be the number of column like following

```
th:nth-child(1){
    width: 45px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
th:nth-child(2){
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
th:nth-child(3){
    width: 20px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```